# How to prove $a+b\sqrt{2}=0$ iff $a=b=0$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to prove for $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$

\begin{align}
a+b\sqrt{2}=0 \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad a=b=0
\end{align}
For $\Leftarrow$ is trivial, now I am in trouble of showing $\Rightarrow$ 
Simply I can say $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational and go proceed, but I want some formal mathematical proof.

Comment: This boils down to the fact that $\sqrt 2$ is irrational. Any mathematical proof you want for the above fact will also prove that. More specifically, prove from the above that if the left hand side is true, then $a,b$ can be chosen to be integers. Then, prove that if $a$ and $b$ are the smallest possible solutions in absolute value, you can find solutions smaller than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $a+b\sqrt{2}=0$, with $b\neq 0$. Then $a=p/q \space(q\neq 0), b=r/s \space (r \neq 0)$ Then $\sqrt{2}=\frac{-ps}{qr}$ so square both sides and proceed with your regular 'square root 2 is irrational' proof.

Answer (score 3):

If $b=0$ or $a=0$, we are done (!). So assume $b\neq 0, a\neq 0$. Then we have
$$\sqrt{2} = -\frac{a}{b}.$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Assume:($a\neq b\neq 0$)
$$a+b\sqrt{2}=0$$
$$(a+b\sqrt{2})(\frac{a-b\sqrt{2}}{a-b\sqrt{2}})=0$$
$$\frac{a^2-2b^2}{a-b\sqrt{2}}=0$$
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
a^2-2b^2=0 &  & \\ 
 a-b\sqrt{2}\neq 0&  & 
\end{matrix}\right.$$
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{a}{b}=\sqrt{2} &  & \\ 
 \frac{a}{b}\neq \sqrt{2}&  & 
\end{matrix}\right.$$
Contradiction

So:($a=b=0$) for $a+b\sqrt{2}=0$