# How to prove $ a + b \sqrt[3]{2} + c\sqrt[3]{4} =0$ iff $a=b=c=0 $

Tags: elementary-number-theory

From the extension of my previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2421046/how-to-prove-ab-sqrt2-0-iff-a-b-0) 
For $a,b,c\in \mathbb{Q}$ 
\begin{align}
 a + b \sqrt[3]{2}  + c\sqrt[3]{4} =0 \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad a=b=c=0 
\end{align}
again also one direction is easy, but how about other direction?

Comment: Instead of making a new question you could have appended your previous one.

Comment: @AaronQuitta I believe making a new question is considered to be better practice

Comment: This question asks about integers, but if you look at the answers, some of the deal with rationals: [Given that $a+b\sqrt[3]{2} +c\sqrt[3]{4} =0$, where $a,b,c$ are integers. Show $a=b=c=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/120489). Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24a%20%2B%20b%20%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7B2%7D%20%2B%20c%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7B4%7D%3D0%24&p=1). (There are probably a few more related questions on this site.)

Comment: This one is precisely this question - just in slightly different formulation: [Proving that $\sqrt[3] {2} ,\sqrt[3] {4},1$ are linearly independent over rationals](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/829005).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As $X^3-2$ is irreducible over the rationals (Eisenstein's criterion)
the least degree of polynomial equation $\alpha=\sqrt[3]2$ satisfies over
$\Bbb Q$ is $3$. So, $a+b\alpha+c\alpha^2=0$ has no nontrivial rational
solution.

Another approach: suppose $a$, $b$, $c$ do exist, not all zero, with
$a+b\alpha+c\alpha^2=0$. We can assume they are integers with no common
factor. Then
$$-a^3=(b\alpha+c\alpha^2)^3=2b^2+6b^2c\alpha +6bc^2\alpha^2+4c^3
=2b^3+4c^3-6abc.$$
This means that $a$ is even. Then
$b+c\alpha+(a/2)\alpha^2=0$. Repeating we get $b$ even, $c$ even,
contradicting $a$, $b$, $c$ having no common factor.