# Prove that if $a+b\sqrt[3]{2} + c\sqrt[3]{4} = 0$ then $a=b=c=0$, where $a,b,c$ are rational numbers

Tags: problem-solving, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, cubics

Trying this for a while and, I found out that if there is another solution $(a_0,b_0,c_0)$, then there is an infinite amount of solutions $(a_0/2,b_0/2,c_0/2), (a_0/4,b_0/4,c_0/4) \ldots$, but I am not sure that this is a contradiction.
Can someone suggest a new insight or help to prove this statement?

Comment: If you can show that if for each *integer* solution $(a,b,c)$ of the equation $(a/2, b/2, c/2)$ is another *integer* solution, then you are done. (And in fact, we can prove this is the case.) Without assuming $(a, b, c)$ are integer, the implication is trivial and does not lead to any contradiction.

Comment: Also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/829005/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2421073/42969 – found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24a%2Bb%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7B2%7D%20%2B%20c%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7B4%7D%20%3D%200%24)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $a + b\sqrt[3]{2} + c\sqrt[3]{4} = 0$, then $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is a solution to $a + bx + cx^2 = 0$. What do we know about quadratic equations with rational coefficients?

Comment: It seems that this has been asked and answered multiple times before.

Comment: Indeed. In that case this question should be closed.